# App not starting on Android Studio emulator

Tags: android-studio

I'm using Android Studio on a Windows 10, and I'm trying to run an app I created.  The emulator starts up with a black screen and then the word `android` pops up, but then nothing happens.  I know other people have posted about this topic, but none of the solutions work.  I don't have an actual phone, so I can't plug it into a real phone.  What should I do here?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
https://www.genymotion.com/#!/

It's a much better emulator than what comes with Android Studio, and it should work. In fact, Google even has plug ins for it because they even admit it's much better.

Comment: So... there doesn't seem to be a free version.

Comment: Is there a free emulator that Google would have plugins for?

Comment: There is a free version. 
You don't need the paid version to have the plugin. (I use this)

Comment: OK then, I'll look into it.  Thanks!